# Force from a large conducting plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, charge

How can I find the distance to a test-charge, hoovering below a conducting plate? Newtons laws applies. 
$$
$$

According to this information, I conclude that the force is equal zero. It is not moving.

I thought that the electric field from a infinitely large conducting plate was constant and
$E\dot\ q=F=m\dot\ g$

The charge has the mass $m$ which gives $ F = m\dot\\g$
Plate att $z=0$

Comment: Please leave comment if you think it was a bad post (down voting) otherwise I won't learn on how to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric field due an infinite conducting plate with a uniform charge distribution (positive or negative) is constant. But as I understand in this problem the conducting plate has no net charge and it is grounded. In that case you can apply method of image to calculate Coulomb force on the  test charge.

The plate is at $z=0$ and let the test charge is at $z=-d$ then  the image charge(opposite sign) is at $z=d$ and Coulomb force of attraction on it is $$F_c=\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 (2d)^2}\hat{z}$$
and force due to gravity is $F_g=-mg{\hat{z}}$. So these two force will be balanced where $|F_c|=|F_g|$ giving $$d=\frac{q}{4\sqrt{mg\pi\epsilon_0}}$$

Comment: Yup that is the Solution. The exercise does not say anything about charge. I just assumed it had surface charge. Thanks!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer then please up vote it and choose it as the correct answer.